# How do I keep my shirt collars from folding the wrong way?

Tags: clothing, laundry

I wear knit shirts mostly and the collars often form a crease in the wrong place, causing the collar to look ugly. When I wash my shirts and put on a hanger I try to remember to leave the collars standing up, so they do not crease, but forget, and I have many shirts with poor crease lines in the collar.

> **What is the best way to prevent collars from creasing, and is there any way to fix shirts that have bad creases in the collar?**

Comment: Do you not iron the shirts once they've dried?

Comment: They are knit shirts.

Comment: I am unaware what that specific type of shirt is but I now assume they're made of a non-iron material

Comment: Hi! By knit shirt, do you mean something that looks like [this](http://www.bigtopshirtshop.com/assets/images/all/Port_And_Company_KP55P_Ash_Grey_Mens_Jersey_Knit_Short_Sleeve_Pocket_Polo_Shirt3.jpg)?

Comment: Yes, a shirt much like that. There are many fabric types. The collars often form a crease, but in the wrong place! When I get knit shirts I make it a habit to always place on the hanger with the collar standing up, and always unfold the colar any time not being worn. Works for new shirts and helps restore old shirts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure right now of how to prevent this, but I know a hack to fix it with a straightening iron. Get the crease you want with your hands as good as you can. Now straighten the crease just like it is hair (you've probably seen a girl do this on TV, or maybe in person). This will keep the creases straight and may help it stay that way too.

[image]

<sup>Image from [WonderfulEngineering](http://wonderfulengineering.com/100-clever-life-improving-ideas-that-you-can-use-in-everyday-life/)</sup>

Comment: Where do people find these neat pictures?

Comment: @subjectivist Where you find everything. Google.

Comment: I must say, you found that very fast fast! Amazing there was a picture to find!

Comment: @subjectivist I have used this before so I was able to answer easily. It was all a matter of looking up "collar and straightening iron"